# Can't Retrieve Resources (rooms) from Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, service, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm stumped.  I'm using Exchange Web Services to retrieve calendar information from both my local and other calendars in my company, but the ".Resources" are always empty.  We use Resources to store conference room information.  Interestingly even ".RequiredAttendees" is empty, but I can retrieve values from the ".DisplayTo" and ".DisplayCc" without issue.  Any suggestions?  I have included a cope snippet below for reference.

```
  CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
  Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(mailboxSMTP);
  FolderId calendarFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mailbox);
  FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = service.FindAppointments(calendarFolder, calendarView);

  foreach (Appointment appointment in findResults.Items)
  {// foreach 1
      ...
```

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

EWS may not request the `Resources` property by default, but you should be able to specifically request it by adding it to the `PropertySet` before calling `FindAppointments`.

```
calendarView.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.Resources);
```

Comment: Hi Jason.  Thanks for your help.  Calling AppointmentSchema.Resources threw an exception, but it did point me in the right direction.  This article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services.aspx) showed how to get to the appointment resources in a way that I would have *never* figured out just using the API documentation ....

Comment: So maybe write the solution ?